# VS Code unable to import numpy (Anaconda Python) but other libraries work

Tags: anaconda, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to import the numpy library in VS Code and its just not working. I initially downloaded Anaconda (did not choose to add to my PATH during the installation process) and everything works fine. I have tried adding in the PATH to my python.exe in the Workspace settings, but that has not solved the problem. I thought it could potentially be an issue with my environment so I created another conda environment (Python plug-in was able to find the new environment) and tried to run my code but I got the same issue.

EDIT: So I figured out that if you open VS Code THROUGH Anaconda, there are no issues at all. But if I open VS Code on it own, I get the error where it is unable to read the packages. At least I have a solution for now but I would love to find out why this happens?

[The error message I got trying to just import numpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuPyb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first configure your vs code to work with your anaconda environment in python, to find the interpreter in visual studio usually it is (ctrl + shift + p) select your python interpreter and then the environment which you want to run when you run the application.